# How to update ListBox using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, inotifypropertychanged

I have a calender and I nested a itemscontrol within the calendars itemscontrol so that I can display events in the gridcell(date) that I want to make an event for. The calender is 7 columns and 6 rows. Right now I'm just using a listbox to actually display the event(Titles). I can add items on startup but I want to be able to add/remove/change once the program is already running. I have tried INotifyPropertyChanged once before and I could not figure it out for the life of me. If someone can take what i have and show me or give me tips on how I can do this, I would really appreciate it.

**The class where I can add(items) before startup:**

```
public class eventProperties : ObservableCollection<eventsTitles>
{
    //public string Eventer { get; set; }

    public eventProperties() : base() 
    {
        Add(new eventsTitles("First Test"));
        Add(new eventsTitles("First Test#2"));

    }
```

This is window(class) that pops up when I want to add an event once the program is up and running already. I need to figure out how to add items from using this window and how to add it to a certain date(gridcell)

```
    public Event(MainWindow parentform)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _parentForm = parentform;
        //this.month = month;
        //this.day = day;
        //this.year = year;
        lblCreateEvent.Content = "Create Event For " + month + " / " + day + " / " + year;

    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        month = Convert.ToInt32(txtMonth.Text);
        day = Convert.ToInt32(txtDay.Text);
        year = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text);



        Schedule sched = new Schedule();
        DateTime curr = DateTime.Now;
        int[] m = new int[7];
        DateTime newcurr = new DateTime(year, month, day);

        var cal = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
        var ms = cal.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(newcurr.Year, newcurr.Month, 1), System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);

           // for (var i = 1; newcurr.Month == 11; newcurr = newcurr.AddDays(1))
           // {

                var month_week = (newcurr.Day / 7);
                sched.MonthWeek = newcurr.GetWeekOfMonth().ToString();
                sched.Month = newcurr.Month.ToString();
                sched.Year = newcurr.Year.ToString();
                sched.day = newcurr.Day.ToString();
                sched.WeekOfYear = cal.GetWeekOfYear(newcurr, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToString();
                sched.dayofweek = newcurr.DayOfWeek.ToString();


                //Here is where the calender is created. By looping through all the days in the selected month it will find the weeknumber and day of the week -->
                // that that particular date belongs to and place in the correct gridcell.
                _parentForm.bindings.schedule.Add(new Schedule { WeekNo = newcurr.GetWeekOfMonth() - 1, WeekDay = (int)newcurr.DayOfWeek, day = newcurr.Day.ToString(), eventTitle = "Camper Calender"    });
```

This is the actual calender XAML where I need to bind everything.

```
     </customgridcontrol:GridControl>


     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="{Binding day}" Width="175" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Name="btnCalenderDate" Click="btnCalenderDate_Click" Loaded="btnCalenderDate_Loaded" Height="18" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold">
                        </Button>

                        <ItemsControl  Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                <src:eventProperties x:Key="dataList"/>
                            </ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <ItemsControl.Items>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source= {StaticResource dataList} }" DisplayMemberPath="EventTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">            
                                </ListBox>
                            </ItemsControl.Items>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

            <Style >        
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding WeekDay}"  />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding WeekNo}" />
            </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

eventTitles Class

```
  namespace Camp_
  {
       public class eventsTitles
       {
            public string eventTitle {get; set;} 

            public eventsTitles()//String ev)
            {
               // this.eventTitle = ev;
            }

            public string EventTitle
            {
                get { return eventTitle; }
                set { eventTitle = value; }
            }
       }        
  }
```

Comment: Could you show us the implementation of `eventsTitles` class, that part is imp for answering properly...

Comment: Why are you making a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection`? Why not just add a property on your `day` class that is of type `ObservableCollection<eventTitle>`?

Comment: @Rachel I see this quite a lot on here and have never understood why people do it.  I can only assume that there is a tutorial somewhere that does this in an example

Comment: there is, I got example off of msdn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Harsh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065771/how-to-update-listbox-using-inotifypropertychanged/8066060#8066060) is correct for how you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, however you only need to implement that for single properties. If you're looking to notify the UI that a Collection has changed, use the `ObservableCollection` class

So if you had a Label containing `Event.EventTitle`, and you wanted to change the `EventTitle` in the code-behind, you would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `EventClass` so that when you updated `myEvent.EventTitle` the Label in the UI would automatically update to the new value.

If you have a ListBox (or ItemsControl) which you want to automatically update when you add or delete items to/from a Collection, simply bind the `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection` property, which will automatically update the UI when items get added or removed from it.

For example,

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
         <Button Content="{Binding day}" Click="AddEvent" />

         <ItemsControl Height="60" ItemsSource="{Binding Events}">
             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EventTitle}" />
                 <DataTemplate>
             </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

In this example, your `Schedule` class would have a property called `Events` which is an `ObservableCollection<Event>`. To add a new event you can use something like this:

```
void AddEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the DataContext for the Button, which should be of type Schedule
    Schedule day = (sender as Button).DataContext as Schedule;

    // Add New Event. Since this is an ObservableCollection, UI will automatically update
    day.Events.Add(new Event { EventTitle = "Test Event" });
}
```

As a side note, you should check out some [.Net naming conventions](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices)

Comment: I'm getting an error for Button saying no namespace or definition found. (sender as "Button") . Any ideas

Comment: @TMan You need to import the namespace `System.Windows.Controls`

Comment: Ok I do have a quick question though. I have a schedule.cs that just has the properties for the ObservableCollection<schedule> and then I have a schedulePage.xaml.cs, this is the page that shows the calender and where I'm putting all the xaml info at. But the first itemscontrol(calender) in schedulePage.xaml.cs binds to schedule.cs so everything you told me should go in schedule.cs or schedulePage.xaml.cs, I tried schedulePage and when I go to click button it says a window has to be root of tree. Also My Event class is also a window which explains error, should I make a separate event.cs?

Comment: @TMan Not sure I understand what you're asking, but yes you should have a separate `Event.cs` for the `Event` class which contains properties that are specific to an `Event` (Name, Description, Date, etc)

Comment: and that Event.cs should be what I use for the observableCollection right?

Comment: Also one more question, my schedulePage.xaml is giving error saying AddEvent has no definition and/or no extension. Would I be missing a reference somewhere?

Comment: Finnallyyyy lol I think I got it. Right now I just have EventTitle set on "test event", like above. But when I click the button it works, so now all I have to do is figure out how to connect all that to the event window so that when I click on the button, a window will pop up and let the user create a custom event with custom title. I couldn't have done all this without you, thanks, still a lot to do though.

Comment: @TMan Glad you got it working, and goodluck with the popup (I have a feeling I'll be hearing from you again.... :) I could have mis-typed the button's click event definition since I didn't use a compiler for it

Comment: Haha your my best resource that's for sure. Thanks for help. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking that `eventTitles` must be having some issue of not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so here is the details for implementing.

**Supposing eventTitles class**

```
public class eventTitles : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _eventtitle = string.Empty;

    public string EventTitle
    {
       get {return _eventtitle;}

        set
        {
            if (value != _eventtitle)
            {
                _eventtitle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("EventTitle");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

For further reference you could check at this [MSDN Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx).